# Rails 3.1 partial fallback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial, fallback

I don't quite understand why the new feature of partial rendering doesn't always kick in.
For example with this code:

```
= render(:partial => "pages/#{foo}/data")
```

it will never fallback to the partial `pages/_data.html.erb` if `pages/test/_data.html.erb` doesn't exist. How can I get this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Something you can do is :

```
= render(:partial => "pages/#{foo}/data") rescue render(:partial => "pages/data")
```

But I would be interested if someone has a better solution, this one is not elegant especially when you have some variables to pass to the partial. At least It can be better if handled by a helper.

Comment: Worked for me -- I was more [explicit about the rescue](https://gist.github.com/reagent/6690353) to make sure other exceptions bubbled up.

Comment: problem here is that if the rendering of ```"pages/#{foo}/data"``` throws some exception, it also falls back (swallowing the exceptions), which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of partials is not that they are small, standalone chunks of HTML to render, but rather bits and pieces of abstraction that you can use to organize your code in a more coherent manner.

As I see it, partials are created to be used in one or more places such that the file does not become cluttered, they're not used to simply be rendered by themselves.  I could be mistaken, however.